# Grouping columns with similar names in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to do EDA for a kaggle dataset (https://www.kaggle.com/christianlillelund/csgo-round-winner-classification) where there are two teams and every column is repeated for both teams. E.g.
Team-1 Score, Team-2 Score, Team-1 Time, Team-2 Time, Team-1 map, Team-2 map...etc.

I would like to group the columns by Team, how can I achieve that?

Thanks

Comment: Grouping sounds much like `GROUP BY`, but you probably mean something in the direction of sorting, I guess.

Comment: I want to group by teams, and not sort. what do you recommend? Its almost like extracting the team name from the column name and then grouping it.

Comment: Pandas groupby can take a function. You can write your own function to see if the column name contains "1" or "2"

Comment: please show input sample and desired output